# Barometer data from Adruino to RPi. Python error with readline()

Tags: python, mysql, readline

Been trying to fix this. The barometer data on the Adruino looks like this:

1008.94
1008.95
1008.94

Which I'm happy with. These get "read" every 10 second for now.

The problem is with my python script. I can read and write all the data to my mySQLdb. But the the data is not always good. It will go like something like:

1008.94
108.95
108.94
1008.96

The "lost zero" or other value always appears on the Adruino's serial monitor.

How can I get the python script to read the whole xxxx.xx line? Just thought even at times of low pressure xxx.xx.

Here is my python code:

```
import MySQLdb
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "pword","weather")
cursor = db.cursor()

while 1:
#       print ("Waiting for data...")
#       print("")
        x = ser.readline()
        clock = (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        print x
#       print ("Collecting data...")
        x = x
#       print ("Inserting to database...")
#       print ("")
        sql = ("""INSERT INTO WeatherP (pres, Time) VALUES (%s, %s)""", (x, clock,))
        cursor.execute(*sql)
        db.commit()
#
```

Thank you.
Tinus

Answer (score 0):

I found the following [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24075787/):

`ser.read(ser.inWaiting())`

According to the pySerial [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html?highlight=inwaiting#serial.Serial.in_waiting) `inWaiting()` does return the size of the received data in the buffer. This could solve your problem because the read function has a size of data it takes given by a parameter (in your case 1 byte since you haven't specified) if the received data is larger it might cause such problems.